# Poner diferente id en angular

Tags: angular

- Tengo un array con información que se guarda en una card, puse un
  botón para leer mas, todo bien, pero cuando presiono el leer mas,
  abre también el texto de los demás cards, alguna manera para que el
  leer mas se active en el card donde presione el botón osea
  "individualmente" y en los demás permanezca normal si es que no
  también le presiono
  **Tengo entendido que tienen que tener diferente id, pero no tengo ni idea de como ponerle diferente id en esa card**

### **https://vimeo.com/495888907**

```
<div class="social-box">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 text-center" *ngFor="let card of card ">
        <div class="box">

          <div class="box-title">
            <h3>{{card.title}}</h3>
            <h6>{{card.negocio}}</h6>
          </div>

          <div id="demo" class="box-text collapse">
            {{card.descripcion}}
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Leer mas</button>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al `*ngFor` agregale una variable para obtener el índice de la iteración `let i = index`, luego usa ese índice para crear ids únicos `id="demo{{i}}"`, `data-target="#demo{{i}}"`

```
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 text-center" *ngFor="let card of card; let i = index">
    <div class="box">

      <div class="box-title">
        <h3>{{card.title}}</h3>
        <h6>{{card.negocio}}</h6>
      </div>

      <div id="demo{{i}}" class="box-text collapse">
        {{card.descripcion}}
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{i}}">Leer mas</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: data-target="#demo{{i}}" Porque me marca error en esa parte?

Comment: olvidalo, ya lo arregle cambiandolo a attr.data-target="#demo{{i}}", muchisimas gracias por la explicacion y la ayuda bro se agradece

Answer (score 0):

Para diferenciar entre las *cards*, tienes que diferenciarlos mediante el id y el data-target. Entonces te quedaría algo como lo siguiente.

```html
 <div id="'card_'+{{card.id}}" class="box-text collapse">
            {{card.descripcion}}
 </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="collapse" datatarget="'#card_'+{{card.id}}">Leer mas</button>
```

Comment: listo, muchisimas gracias